# Should we prevent the use of "???"?

Tags: discussion

When submitting a question, the SE site check for classical words indicating that the question is potentially of low quality and in such case prevents the submission of the question and returns a message to the user.

There are key issues of grammars that could be filtered this way too. The most classical examples are the use of "???" or "!!!". Should we prevent the use of such expression in the text?

Note, that we should always allow for the use of these expression in quotes format and in code format.

Comment: That would be great. I think we also need to ban the use of the word "question" in question titles.

Comment: I already edit and remove multiple exclamation and question marks. We should do the same with fat or italic parts of questions. No need to have this shouting in your face.